# How to return data from controller method to a jquery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My Jquery ajax call -

```
         var formdata = $('#emailrequest').serializeArray();

          // Ajax call to server
          $.ajax({
              url: sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/ProcessEmailrequest',
              type: 'POST',
              data: formdata,
              sucess: function(data) {
                  alert(data.sucess);
              },
              error: function() {
                  alert('error');
              }
              });//End Ajax
```

My controller -

```
    public ActionResult ProcessEmailrequest()
            {

              // some code

            // retun the response 
            return Json(new {success = true});
```

But all is get is error in alert . Where am I going wrong? Please help . I just need to return a confimation from controller , be it any format.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: change your error handler function to : `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}` so you can meaningful error.

Comment: inspect the actual request in network tab of browser console. Without meaningful troubleshooting information nobody can help you without a lot of guess work

Comment: If you getting an error is likely that you controller is throwing an exception. Debug your code!

Answer (score 1):

You spelled success wrong so it will never hit. It should work with the ActionResult but a JsonResult is better.

```
         var formdata = $('#emailrequest').serializeArray();

      // Ajax call to server
      $.ajax({
          url: sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/ProcessEmailrequest',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formdata,
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data.sucess);
          },
          error: function() {
              alert('error');
          }
          });//End Ajax
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your controller method return type to JsonResult instead of ActionResult, so:

```
 public JsonResult ProcessEmailrequest()
 {
     // some code

     // retun the response 
     return Json(new {success = true});
 }
```

If that doesn't help set your ajax error function to receive following parameters:

```
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      ...
 }
```

Then debug in browser and set a break point to error function and in the xhr object (responseText property) you'll be able to see exact error.

Answer (score 0):

you shoudn't return json like that. **use [ ] instead of {}**

```
public JsonResult ProcessEmailrequest()
 {
     // some code

     // retun the response 
     return Json(new [success = true]);
 }
```